# Grabbing contents of Object from S3 via PHP SDK 2?

Tags: php, sdk, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I have been trying to figure out how to grab contents from an S3 bucket to include in a ZipArchive for a client who is storing files on S3, they now need to create reports that hold the files that were pushed up to S3 by their customers. I have tried the following with the PHP SDK 2 API (Installed with PEAR):

```
require 'AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\Common\Enum\Region;

$config = array(
    'key'    => 'the-aws-key',
    'secret' => 'the-aws-secret',
    'region' => Region::US_EAST_1
);

$aws_s3 = S3Client::factory($config);
$app_config['s3']['bucket'] = 'the-aws-bucket';
$app_config['s3']['prefix'] = '';
$attach_name = 'hosted-test-file.jpg';
try {
    $result = $aws_s3->getObject(
        array(
            'Bucket' => $app_config['s3']['bucket'],
            'Key' => $app_config['s3']['prefix'].$attach_name
        )
    );
    var_dump($result);
    $body = $result->get('Body');
    var_dump($body);
    $handle = fopen('php://temp', 'r');
    $content = stream_get_contents($handle);
    echo "String length: ".strlen($content);
} catch(Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception $e) {
    echo "Request failed.<br />";
}
```

However, all it returns is an `Guzzle\Http\EntityBody` object, not sure how to grab the actual content so I can push it into the zip file.

[Grabbing Object](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_getObject)

```
object(Guzzle\Service\Resource\Model)[126]
    protected 'structure' => object(Guzzle\Service\Description\Parameter)[109]
    protected 'name' => null
    protected 'description' => null
    protected 'type' => string 'object' (length = 6)
    protected 'required' => boolean false
    protected 'enum' => null
    protected 'additionalProperties' => boolean true
    protected 'items' => null
    protected 'parent' => null
    protected 'ref' => null
    protected 'format' => null
    protected 'data' => array (size = 11)
        'Body' => object(Guzzle\Http\EntityBody)[97]
            protected 'contentEncoding' => boolean false
            protected 'rewindFunction' => null
            protected 'stream' => resource(292, stream)
            protected 'size' => int 3078337
            protected 'cache' => array (size = 9)
            ...
        'DeleteMarker' => string '' (length = 0)
        'Expiration' => string '' (length = 0)
        'WebsiteRedirectLocation' => string '' (length = 0)
        'LastModified' => string 'Fri, 30 Nov 2012 21:07:30 GMT' (length = 29)
        'ContentType' => string 'binary/octet-stream' (length = 19)
        'ContentLength' => string '3078337' (length = 7)
        'ETag' => string '"the-etag-of-the-file"' (length = 34)
        'ServerSideEncryption' => string '' (length = 0)
        'VersionId' => string '' (length = 0)
        'RequestId' => string 'request-id' (length = 16)
```

[Returned from Body](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Guzzle.Http.EntityBody.html)

```
object(Guzzle\Http\EntityBody)[96]
    protected 'contentEncoding' => boolean false
    protected 'rewindFunction' => null
    protected 'stream' => resource(292, stream)
    protected 'size' => int 3078337
    protected 'cache' => array (size = 9)
        'wrapper_type' => string 'php' (length = 3)
        'stream_type' => string 'temp' (length = 4)
        'mode' => string 'w+b' (length = 3)
        'unread_bytes' => int 0
        'seekable' => boolean true
        'uri' => string 'php://temp' (length = 10)
        'is_local' => boolean true
        'is_readable' => boolean true
        'is_writable' => boolean true

// Echo of strlen()
String length: 0
```

Any information would be high appreciated, thanks!

**Solution**

It me a while to figure it out but I was able to find a gist that pointed me in the right direction, in order to get the contents of the file you need to do the following:

```
require 'AWSSDKforPHP/aws.phar';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\Common\Enum\Region;

$config = array(
    'key'    => 'the-aws-key',
    'secret' => 'the-aws-secret',
    'region' => Region::US_EAST_1
);

$aws_s3 = S3Client::factory($config);
$app_config['s3']['bucket'] = 'the-aws-bucket';
$app_config['s3']['prefix'] = '';
$attach_name = 'hosted-test-file.jpg';
try {
    $result = $aws_s3->getObject(
        array(
            'Bucket' => $app_config['s3']['bucket'],
            'Key' => $app_config['s3']['prefix'].$attach_name
        )
    );
    $body = $result->get('Body');
    $body->rewind();
    $content = $body->read($result['ContentLength']);
} catch(Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception $e) {
    echo "Request failed.<br />";
}
```

Comment: If you really need to grab the underlying PHP stream resource from an EntityBody object, you can all the `getStream()` method. See http://guzzlephp.org/api/class-Guzzle.Http.EntityBody.html for API documentation of the EntityBody object.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The body of the response is stored in a `Guzzle\Http\EntityBody` object. This is used to protect your application from downloading extremely large files and running out of memory.

If you need to use the contents of the the EntityBody object as a string, you can cast the object to a string:

```
$result = $s3Client->getObject(array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key'    => $key
));

// Cast as a string
$bodyAsString = (string) $result['Body'];

// or call __toString directly
$bodyAsString = $result['Body']->__toString();
```

You can also download directly to the target file if needed:

```
use Guzzle\Http\EntityBody;

$s3Client->getObject(array(
  'Bucket' => $bucket,
  'Key'    => $key,
  'command.response_body' => EntityBody::factory(fopen("/tmp/{$key}", 'w+'))
));
```

Comment: I think there's a missing '$result->toArray()' before doing $result['Body']

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
$tempSave = 'path/to/save/filename.txt';

return $this->S3->getObject([
     'Bucket' => 'test',
     'Key'    => $keyName,
     'SaveAs' => $tempSave,
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

When calling `getObject`, you can pass in an array of options. In these options, you can specify if you want to download the object to your file system.

```
$bucket = "bucketName";
$file = "fileName";
$downloadTo = "path/to/save";

$opts = array(  // array of options
    'fileDownload' => $downloadTo . $file   // tells the SDK to download the 
                                             // file to this location
);

$result = $aws_s3->getObject($bucket, $file, $opts);
```

[getObject Reference](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonS3/get_object)

Comment: I am using the PHP SDK 2, that is the first SDK. The appropriate docs are [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html).

Comment: Ah, my bad. Ignore my answer in that case. SDK 2's docs are sadly lacking compared to 1.5's docs.

Comment: Yep, which is why I finally decided to turn to stackoverflow for the answer since I have tried everything in the docs lol. I am sure someone has figured it out. :)

Comment: Any reason why you couldn't just use the SDK 1.5 if all else fails?

Comment: Well I am already using it for most of the rest of the project, just got stuck on this part, which I might end up having to use, but we shall see.

Answer (score 0):

I am not that familiar with the version 2.00 SDK, but it looks like you have been passed a stream context on `php://temp`.  From looking at your updated question and from a brief glance at the documentation, it seems the stream may be available as:

```
$result = $aws_s3->getObject(
    array(
        'Bucket' => $app_config['s3']['bucket'],
        'Key' => $app_config['s3']['prefix'].$attach_name
    )
);
$stream = $result->get('stream');
$content = file_get_contents($stream);
```

Comment: Oh is that what that meant? Let me check it real quick.

Comment: I added more of the output from the objects, it looks like it is trying to return `binary/octet-stream`.

Comment: I looked through your updated question and the SDK documentation and have updated my answer. It seems the stream handle is already available on both the `Guzzle\Service\Resource\Model` object and the `Guzzle\Http\EntityBody` object nested inside of it.  My answer is just getting the stream from the top level object.

Comment: Trying to get the `stream` returns false because the `Guzzle\Http\EntityBody` is included in `Body`. The top level doesn't have a `stream` sadly. The above is two var_dumps.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
   $o_iter = $client->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
    'Bucket' => $bucketname
   ));
   foreach ($o_iter as $o) {
    echo "{$o['Key']}\t{$o['Size']}\t{$o['LastModified']}\n";
   }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not generally helpful. Please explain what you are doing and why.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question asked.